# How do I search for a job change which has different skill requirement than the ones I have experience in?

Tags: job-change

I am experienced in PHP and Laravel in a startup company in India. It's been a year. I started to learn a lot of things initially. But with the passage of time, the workload is somewhat more, and the pay is very less. I am getting around 179 usd per month for Software development.

So, I decided to switch my company. Now I recently bought a Python course. But whenever I search for companies requiring Python/ Django, they always want experience in Python/Django itself. They generally dont reply , but even when they do, they answer negatively stating, I need experience in Python.

I am halfway in it, but I am enjoying it so much. At first, I wanted to switch for money only. But, now I want both money and skill as Python/Django.

However, there arent any projects in Python/Django in our company.

In a more generalised sense, how do I apply for an opening in a company whose skillset demands are different from the ones that I have experience in?

Comment: Change of carrier usually comes with salary / benefits / position drop

Comment: @Strader Changing programming languages isn't a change in career.  I've changed from C to C++ to Java to Ruby to Kotlin.  None came with a drop.  Several came with raises.  Programming skill is programming skill, unless there's a crushing need smart companies hire good devs and let them learn the tools.

Comment: @GabeSechan I only said usually, Also C -> C++ is natural technological progress.

Comment: @Strader  And you're wrong with that, because this isn't a case of changing careers, but of technologies within a career.  Which is a fairly normal thing to do, with no loss of salary from it.  (You're also wrong that C->C++ isn't a huge change in languages, but this isn't a tech site so I'll skip that).

Comment: @GabeSechan each language has its purpose, as an example switching from back-end to front-end may not be as smooth as you imply

Answer (score -1):

The fact is, not many companies are willing to hire people and pay them for some time until they reach a certain level of experience.

I would suggest either trying to search for PHP jobs that mention the need to also know some basics of Python / Django or making your own application that you can show as relevant experience.

So it boils down to either work where you have experience with the possibility to learn about the other where you need to collect experience, or you just have a firm proof of knowledge without official experience.

Comment: This isn't my experience in programming at all.  Every place I've ever worked has hired people and let them learn the language/framework/libraries on the job.  Its unavoidable in the industry, and a decent programmer is expected to be able to come up to speed in a new language to the point of being productive in a few weeks.  The core concepts of computer science stay the same, its not all that hard.

Comment: @GabeSechan It really depends. Nobody will hire a person and tell them go learn what you need to learn to work. Usually letting someone learn means they have more than enough basis knowledge or they have other knowledge that they already use at the job and are just expanding their knowledge to cover even more. Perhaps I didn't express myself properly, but you need to have something that you can already use, so you also get provided with time to expand knowledge. Otherwise companies would be hiring anyone from the street and just letting them learn how to develop.

Comment: You're just wrong.  My company regularly hires people and tells them they need to learn Ruby-  95% of our hires don't come on board knowing the main language.  I have multiple times in my career came on board and had to learn new languages and frameworks.  Its the norm in programming.  You need to know how to code, but you don't need those specific technologies.  I've switched from firmware to bvack end development to mobile development and back a few times in my career.  Nobody ever blinked at hiring me, even at top of market prices.

Comment: LOL at that "You're just wrong". Your company doesn't represent every company. Mine definitely looks for and only wants people who don't need to learn the main thing they were hired to do. You can't just come to an interview for a Ruby developer knowing only Java. Guess your company really does hire whoever chooses to come by and ask for a job.

Comment: I've done just that.  And for  Java jobs knowing C++, and other configurations.  And not just me-  every dev I know has done this, and gotten hired.  Switching technologies is so common its not even remarked on int he industry.  If you know the fundamentals of programming, you can pick up a new language in weeks and learn as you go.  If you can't-  you have a dead end career.  As for the companies I've worked at-  well, this is the opinion at Facebook, Amazon, Apple, Shopify all of which I worked at, and all of which were language changes for me.